# operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'object' ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to select data from database depending on Session value , but I'm getting this error always 
'operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'object' MVC '

I tried the following code in orders controller and orders view:

```
public ActionResult ordersCash()
{
    return View(db.Lab_orders_Cash.Where(x => x.patient_no == Session["UserpatientNo"]).ToList());
}
```

I tried the solutions in this site by using (int) but its not working :

```
public ActionResult ordersCash()
{
    return View(db.Lab_orders_Cash.Where(x => x.patient_no == (int)Session["UserpatientNo"]).ToList());
}
```

When i used `(int)Session["UserpatientNo"])` i got this error :

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Without where clause i can get all data but i need to filter and search by session value.
How can i solve this error?

Comment: what error do you get using a cast to `(int)`? That should work _if_ the value is actually an int (or implicitly convertible)

Comment: @DStanley  , i got the error in question i added the error , yes the session value integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the session variable into a variable:

```
public ActionResult ordersCash()
{
    int userPatientNum = (int)Session["UserpatientNo"];
    return View(db.Lab_orders_Cash.Where(x => x.patient_no == userPatientNum).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working :)  I need your help in the future i am building new application and I'm new to MVC and i think i will face more errors .